# Change the label text at runtime in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

i have created a group in run time and then added in it two buttons and one label

```
addElement (myGroup )

myGroup.addElement ( button 1 )
myGroup.addElement ( label )
myGroup.addElement ( button 2 )
```

now when i click on one button 2 i can get `event.currentTarget.`

How can i change the text of label using this `event.currentTarget`. How can i target the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this may solve your problem.
When you create the label Object provide it with an `id`. so that you can access the label through out the application using this 'id'. You can change the text by using this `id.text`

Or you can use the group objectId. like this one
 `groupObjectID.getElementAt(index).text`

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the event.currentTarget is Label by casting it using 'as' operator

`var lbl:Label = event.currentTarget as Label;
if (lbl)
{
//do rest of processing
}`

Comment: no mate the current target is button. i want to access the label.

Comment: maybe by getting index of current target button and then accessing the element with index one less than button?

Comment: Yes, either that or defining an id for the label so you don't have to do all of this.

Comment: well iam trying if u can give a hint how would i do that

Comment: var indi:int;
indi = getElementIndex(Button(event.currentTarget));
var label:Label = new Label ();
label = getElementAt(indi-1) as Label;
userName = label.text;  this is the code i am using

Answer (score 0):

Give name to your Label  `label.name='lblSomething'`. 
Then you can access by
`var mylabel:Label = myGroup.getChildByName(lblSomething) as Label`

Answer (score 0):

Try `var labelStr:String = event.currentTarget.label;`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I do recommend you try to create those labels and buttons as either public or private objects whenever possible so that you can always refer to them using the object ID.

This is a good practice as well... just my 2 cents.

```
public var t_label:Label = new Label (); // t_ just stands for temporary... nothing special
myGroup.addElement (this.t_label);
```

Then inside ANY event handler you can write something like this to change the label text.

```
private function onWhateverHandler (event:Event):void
{
    this.t_label.text = "whatever new string value";
}
```